# Ошибка TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Tags: python

Я в Python новичок, на курсе задали задачу написать программу для решения дискриминанта и выдает ошибку. Что не так?

```
a = 12
b = 7
c = 1
if a != 0:
  disc = b**2 - 4 * a * c
  if disc < 0:
    print('корней нет')
  elif disc == 0:
   x = -b / (2 * a)
   print ('двойной корень x =', x)
  else:
   print ('два корня')
   x_1 = (-b + disc**0,5) / (2 * a)
   x_2 = (-b - disc**0,5) / (2 * a)
   print('x_1', x_1)
   print('x_2', x_2)
else:
  print('не квадратное')
print('конец')
```

```
два корня
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-6c46f0fc8169> in <module>()
     11   else:
     12    print ('два корня')
---> 13    x_1 = (-b + disc**0,5) / (2 * a)
     14    x_2 = (-b - disc**0,5) / (2 * a)
     15    print('x_1', x_1)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 3):

Дробная часть числа должна отделяться точкой:

```py
x_1 = (-b + disc**0.5) / (2 * a)
#                 ^^^
```

Вы же отделяете её запятой. Поэтому Python воспринимает выражение как кортеж (`tuple`) из двух элементов:

```py
x_1 = (-b + disc**0,5)  # (-6, 5)
type(x_1)               # <class 'tuple'>
x_1[0]                  # -6
x_1[1]                  # 5
```